# Reducing complexity of code for if-else statements

Tags: java, if-statement, sonarqube

My code analysis plugin is complaining about code complexity in the method that contains following code. I noticed following code looks like it could be combined, but I am not sure how to do it:

```
for(Command command : commands) {
    if (command instanceof AddCommand || command instanceof UpdateCommand) {
        if (!isMaturityDateInPast() && !paymentDueDate().isAfter(LocalDate.now())) {
            command.execute(request);
        }
    } else {
        command.execute(request);
    }
}
```

I tried introducing boolean variable and setting it in both if and else statements, but that just adds more lines of code.
I am not very good when it comes to logically placing parts of code that have something in common. I can tell this `if-else` could be combined, but I don't know how to do it. Can someone  shed some light?

Comment: It looks fine to me. Combining them all into one statement makes it less readable I think, at least to me.

Comment: you can ignore that. it's not an error. the more the lines inside a method, the more it will complain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do early `continue` to avoid the repetition of `command.execute()`.
I don't think it's worth to combine the conditions in one or creating another function for its sake.

```
for(Command command : commands) {
  if (command instanceof AddCommand || command instanceof UpdateCommand) {
    if (isMaturityDateInPast() || paymentDueDate().isAfter(LocalDate.now())) {
        continue;
    }
  }
  command.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the two identical branches by negating the first condition and then or it with the second one.

That, and two small util methods, makes the code a bit nicer:

```
for (Command command : commands) {
    if (!isAddOrUpdate(command) || executeAnyway()) {
        command.execute(request);
    }
}   

private static boolean isAddOrUpdate(Command command) {
    return command instanceof AddCommand || command instanceof UpdateCommand;
}

// Rename this to something that makes sense for your domain
private boolean  executeAnyway(){
    return !isMaturityDateInPast() && !paymentDueDate().isAfter(LocalDate.now());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check for the commands that *aren't* `AddCommand` or `UpdateCommand`, you can get slightly cleaner code:

```
for(Command command : commands) {
    if (!(command instanceof AddCommand || command instanceof UpdateCommand)) {
        command.execute(request);
    } else if(!isMaturityDateInPast() && !paymentDueDate().isAfter(LocalDate.now())) {
            command.execute(request);
    }
}
```

But this is marginally better at best. There's really nothing wrong at all with having nested if clauses. In fact, in reality this is an if clause nested in the else clause, but since Java (as many other languages) allows for the `else if` syntactic sugar, this *looks* cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You could modularize your code a bit more (break down into separate methods).  That may make it more readable/maintainable and should appease the static analysis.

Also, it looks like you may be performing some checks on every iteration when you probably only need to do them once (since the input appears to not change).

It might also help to create some booleans that are more readable and "explain" what you're doing.

```java
boolean isMaturityDateInFuture = !isMaturityDateInPast();
boolean isPaymentDueDateInPast = !paymentDueDate().isAfter(LocalDate.now());

for (Command command : commands) {
    boolean isAddOrUpdate = command instanceof AddCommand || command instanceof UpdateCommand;

    if (!isAddOrUpdate || (isMaturityDateInFuture && isPaymentDueDateInPast)) {
        command.execute(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to split it into multiple methods as that will make it more readable and reduce your method complexity. Example:

```
       for(Command command : commands) {
            if (command instanceof AddCommand || command instanceof UpdateCommand) {
                checkAndExecuteCommand(command,request);

            } else {
                command.execute(request);
            }
        }

        private void checkAndExecuteCommand(Command command,Request request) {
            if (!isMaturityDateInPast() && !paymentDueDate().isAfter(LocalDate.now())) {
                command.execute(request);
            }
        }
```